# API chrome.notifications.onButtonClicked Notification als Parameter

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

If I open a Notification multiple times without refreshing my extension, it executes the Button Listener Code as often as it opens the Notification..

number of notifications opened = x = number of onButtonClicked.addListener executed Code.

I found out that I opened a new onButtonClicked.addListener multiple times.. thats the problem.

Marvin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happend because I opend a new Click Listener every time I opend a new Notification..

Answer (score 1):

Set only a new onButtonClicked.addListener in your script instead of setting a new one every time opening a new Notification.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I think it's a bug in Chrome. I only added the listener once when the page loaded.

My workaround was:

```
var ignoreNotificationClicks = false

function notificationButtonClick (notificationID, buttonId) {
    if (!ignoreNotificationClicks) {

        //Your code here

    }
    ignoreNotificationClicks = true;
    setTimeout(function(){ ignoreNotificationClicks = false }, 500);
}
```

Your code gets run the first time, then waits until half a second after the last duplicate function call before allowing more clicks to work.